# How to add a bean with asynchronous method invocation behavior to the liferay portlet?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, liferay, liferay-6

I run Liferay 6.2 CE. I am trying to declare a bean which method can be invoked asynchronously. But when I call the method, it executes synchronously. Thus I don't understand, what have I missed?

This is my bean:

```
public class MyBean {

    @Async
    public void process(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(new Date());
    }
}
```

I have added the Spring annotations to my project dependencies:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
...
```

I have created **ext-spring.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- activate the @Async annotation -->
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"/>

    <bean id="taskExecutor"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="processor" class="mypackage.MyBean"/>
</beans>
```

This snippet shows how I invoke the method:

```
...
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) PortletBeanLocatorUtil.locate(my_plugin_context_name, "processor");
myBean.process();
...
```

Comment: can you share the code snippet from where you are invoking process() method?

Comment: @premkumar, I have shared the code snippet.

Comment: In all likelihood, I should use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` directly.